# Как форматировать шрифт?

Tags: шрифты, web-fonts

Имеем любой шрифт в формате TTF , и так же имеем любой онлайн конвертер шрифтов в web-fonts - смысл показали на TTF а получаем eot, otf, svg,ttf,woff.

Вопрос : каким образом минуя онлайн сервисы в домашних условиях сделать тоже самое ?

Answer (score 1):

Ну если миновать сервисы, но не миновать ПО, то:
[TransType_4.0.1.5095](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/36a5e38f0cda/TransType_4.0.1.5095.rar)

Comment: эта софтинка тоже самое умеет ?

Comment: Да, позволяет преобразовывать шрифт в формат: PostScript, TrueType и OpenType, а также между платформами PC и Mac.